# Awk or sed to display increment odd & even lines

Tags: awk, sed

Need help to display increment odd & even lines in a text file to screen.

Textfile

```
10101 
AsPO4IF+tGU=
01010 
WvTzUYrxvXY=
00101
CfZzsDDKW98=
```

Stuck at the following script.

```
result=Textfile
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
echo "`awk or sed odd line $result`" "`awk or sed even line $result`"
done < "$result"
```

Output needed

```
"AsPO4IF+tGU=" "10101" 

"WvTzUYrxvXY=" "01010" 

"CfZzsDDKW98=" "00101"
```

Stops script once EOF in Textfile has reached.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: Are the trailing whitespaces after `10101` and `01010` intended?

Comment: Thanks all for your amazing responses...the answers was what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop lines of a file, `awk` is expert in exactly that:

```
awk '
    NR%2 != 0 {last=$0}
    NR%2 == 0 {printf "\"%s\" \"%s\"\n",$0,last}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you don't need to have an external loop either:

```
sed -E '$!N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/"\2" "\1"/' file
```

- `-E` is to use extended regular expression, which makes the `()`easier to read
- `$!N` always joins (`N`) two lines in the pattern space except for the last line (`$!`), if there should be an unpaired line
- `s/(.*)\n(.*)/"\2" "\1"/` flips both lines, replaces the newline with a whitespace and adds the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

command:

```
sed "N;s/\n/ /g" filename | awk '{print $2,$1}'| sed 's/^/"/g'| sed 's/$/"/g'| sed 's/=/"&"/g'
```

output

```
"AsPO4IF+tGU"=" 10101"
"WvTzUYrxvXY"=" 01010"
"CfZzsDDKW98"=" 00101"
```